# SPARQL query QueryParseException ^owl, endpoint ok, Jena not ok

Tags: sparql, jena

I have the following SPARQL query:

```
PREFIX owl <http://www.w3.org/2002/07/owl#>
PREFIX dbo: <http://dbpedia.org/ontology/>
SELECT Distinct(?so2) WHERE {
 ?city a dbo:City ; (owl:sameAs|^owl:sameAs)* ?so2 .
 filter( !regex(str(?so2), "dbpedia" ))
} order by ?city
```

This works at http://dbpedia.org/sparql but not using with Java/Jena.

Jena I receive this error:

```
Exception in thread "main" org.apache.jena.query.QueryParseException: Lexical error at line 1, column 11.  Encountered: " " (32), after : "owl"
```

So, what is wrong with:

```
(owl:sameAs|^owl:sameAs)*
```

I'm using the latest version of Jena (3.9.0).

snapshot of my java code, where the error comes from:

```
Query query = QueryFactory.create(cSparql);
QueryExecution qexec = QueryExecutionFactory.sparqlService(endPoint, query);
```

If I use the following code:

```
QueryEngineHTTP qexec = new QueryEngineHTTP(endPoint, cSparql);
```

I receive this error:

```
HttpException: 400 HTTP 400 error making the query: Bad Request
```

Why this happens and how to execute with Java/Jena?

Thanks in advance,

Comment: The prefix syntax is wrong, just add ':' after prefix declaration of 'owl'  ... not sure why it is accepted like that in dbpedia endpoint ...

Comment: @DamyanOgnyanov it isn't accepted there either, so it's just a typo in the Java code.

Comment: But there is also another issue with the query, it must be `SELECT DISTINCT  ?so2`, i.e. without the braces. Yes, Virtuoso accepts this, but usually their parser is more relaxed and also supports SQL close syntax. That's why also commas between projection variables are supported in Virtuoso, but not in the official SPARQL standard.

Answer (score 3):

Your query isn't proper SPARQL.  As noted in comments, Virtuoso accepts a number of SQL-isms in SPARQL, but this flexibility is not found in all SPARQL processors.

Your query should be (with some whitespace adjustments for readability) --

```
PREFIX owl: <http://www.w3.org/2002/07/owl#>
PREFIX dbo: <http://dbpedia.org/ontology/>

SELECT DISTINCT ?so2  
WHERE
  {
    ?city  a                          dbo:City ; 
           (owl:sameAs|^owl:sameAs)*  ?so2 .
    FILTER ( !regex(str(?so2), "dbpedia" ) )
  } 
ORDER BY ?city
```

Answer (score 0):

Perfect, works:
this way:

```
PREFIX owl: <http://www.w3.org/2002/07/owl#>
PREFIX dbo: <http://dbpedia.org/ontology/>

SELECT DISTINCT ?so2  
WHERE
  {
    ?city  a                          dbo:City ; 
           (owl:sameAs|^owl:sameAs)*  ?so2 .
    FILTER ( !regex(str(?so2), "dbpedia" ) )
  } 
ORDER BY ?city
```

and this way:

```
PREFIX owl: <http://www.w3.org/2002/07/owl#>
PREFIX dbo: <http://dbpedia.org/ontology/>
SELECT Distinct(?so2) WHERE {
 ?city a dbo:City ; owl:sameAs|^owl:sameAs* ?so2 .
 filter( !regex(str(?so2), "dbpedia" ))
} order by ?city
```

Thanks a lot guys !!!

Comment: Remember that the second formulation (`Distinct(?so2)`) is not likely to work against any non-Virtuoso endpoint. So this answer is not recommended for general use...